# Show hidden div containing input buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I'm currently trying to a show hidden `<div>` that includes two input buttons after clicking a button.

Here's my HTML;

```
// Button to show <div>
<input type="button" value="Show" id="show" class="show"/>

<div id="hiddenDiv" style="font-size:20px;">                                    
    <input type="button" class="btn-default" id="button1" />                                                                 
    <input type="button" class="btn-default" id="button2" />                                                                                                                
</div>
```

jQuery;

```
  $("#hiddenDiv").hide();
    $("#show").click(function () {
        $("#hiddenDiv").animate({ "opacity": "show", "top": "250px" }, "slow");
    });
```

I can't get the input buttons to show up after clicking the `show` -button. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/9cyh0wv2/), it seems to work just fine. Did you remember to include jQuery and use `document.ready`

Comment: do you see any error in console?

Comment: Are you running the code after the html or before? If you are running it before the html, then the html elements have not been created and javascript won't be able to find them.

Comment: @adeneo Yes i added the `document.ready` and jQuery. The buttons are completely visible even before I press the button. After the button press they disappear.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I run the jQuery before the HTML part

Comment: @derloopkat No errors.

Comment: as for me, i need more information

Comment: @TechCount Since you run it before, you need to place it in an onReady event: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ Otherwise you need to move it to the end of the html document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are running your JavaScript before the html has loaded you need to place the code in a `ready()` event which will trigger once the html has loaded on the page.

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#hiddenDiv").hide();
        $("#show").click(function () {
            $("#hiddenDiv").animate({ "opacity": "show", "top": "250px" }, "slow");
        });
    });
</script>
<input type="button" value="Show" id="show" class="show"/>

<div id="hiddenDiv" style="font-size:20px;">                                    
    <input type="button" class="btn-default" id="button1" />                                                                 
    <input type="button" class="btn-default" id="button2" />                                                                                                                
</div>
```

For more information on the `ready()` event see the documentation:

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Thank you. I still can't see the hidden input buttons inside the `<div>`, but the reason for it might be that its located inside a bootstrap panel and I just need to resize them to show up.

Comment: Your input buttons don't have a `value=""` attribute, that could be the reason.